# Parent can change color on click, but the child can not

Tags: click, parent-child

Each is a div by clicking. Clicking on parent and parent2 can change color (), but clicking on child-div (some_id1, some_id2) can not change the color. How can this be avoided, every div should be clicked and that color can be changed?
Of course later I would add more divs.

```
<style> 
#some_id1{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin: 10px;
background-color: red;
}

#some_id2{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin: 10px;
background-color: red;
}

#parent{
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: blue;
}

#parent2{
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<input type="color" id="divbackgroundcolor" onchange="ColorChange()">

<div class="some_style" id="parent">
     <div class="some_style" id="some_id1"></div>
     <div class="some_style" id="some_id2"></div>
</div>

<div class="some_style" id="parent2"></div>

<script>
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var divCount = div.length;
var clickedDivId

for (var i = 0; i < divCount; i += 1) {
    div[i].onclick = function(e) {
        clickedDivId = this.id
    };
} 

function ColorChange(){
        var x = document.getElementById("divbackgroundcolor").value;
        document.getElementById(clickedDivId).style.backgroundColor = x;
}        
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

y.addEventListener('click', function (e) { event.stopPropagation(); 
clickedDivId = this.id;

Answer (score 0):

A very interesting question. This can be explained by the fact that a parent is always the one being clicked in the action, if we edit your code to use the section tag, we can see that the bottom section is clicked and can be changed, but the top two child items never change or register as being clicked because the parent is.

```
<style> 
    #some_id1{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    }

    #some_id2{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    }

    #parent{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
    }

    #parent2{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<input type="color" id="divbackgroundcolor" onchange="ColorChange()">

<div  class="some_style" id="parent">
     <section class="some_style" id="some_id1"></section>
     <section class="some_style" id="some_id2"></section>
</div >

<section  class="some_style" id="parent2"></section >

<script>
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("section");
var divCount = div.length;
var clickedDivId

for (var i = 0; i < divCount; i += 1) {
    div[i].onclick = function(e) {
        clickedDivId = this.id
    };
} 

function ColorChange(){
        var x = document.getElementById("divbackgroundcolor").value;
        document.getElementById(clickedDivId).style.backgroundColor = x;
}        
</script>
```

Comment: This does not help. It should be exclusively div. Even with </ section> suddenly the parent div is no longer clicking.
How to make all divs clicks, really challenging, I have no idea...

Comment: The parent will always register a click and not the child item, the use of <section> tags was just for demonstration of this principle. @aldin_abdagic

Comment: I found the answer but another problem appeared. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56204946/add-event-listener-on-new-element-does-not-work